# How can I find files that match a two-line pattern using grep?

Tags: grep

I created a test file with the following:

```
<cert>
</cert>
```

I'm now trying to find this with grep and the following command, but it take forever to run.
How can I search quickly for files that contain adjacent lines like these?

```
tr -d '\n' | grep '<cert></cert>' test.test
```

Answer (score 1):

So, from the comments, you're trying to get the *filenames* that contain an empty `<cert>..</cert>` element. You're using several tools wrong. As @iiSeymour pointed out, `tr` only reads from standard input-- so if you want to use it to select from lots of filenames, you'll need to use a loop. `grep` prints out matching *lines*, not filenames; though you could use `grep -l` to see the filenames instead.

But you're only joining lines because `grep` works one line at a time; so let's use a better tool. Here's how to search with awk:

```shell
awk '/<cert>/ { started=1; } 
   /<\/cert>/ { if (started) { print FILENAME; nextfile;} }
 !/<cert>/ { started = 0; }' file1 file2 *.txt
```

It checks each line and keeps track of whether the previous line matched `<cert>`. (`!/pattern/` sets the flag back to zero on lines not matching `/pattern/`.) Call it with all your files (or with a wildcard like `*.txt`).

And a friendly suggestion: Next time, try each command separately (you've been stuck on this for hours and you still don't know what `grep` does?). And have a quick look at the manual for the tools you want to use. Unix tools are usually too complex for simple trial and error.

Comment: Good approach +1. You could use `BEGINFILE` to improve the readability of the script  `'BEGINFILE{flag=0}/<cert>/{flag=1}/<\/cert>/&&flag{print FILENAME; nextfile}'`

Comment: @iiSeymour, that won't do it: The flag must be reset to zero if the`<cert>` element is not closed on the very next line.

Comment: Oh I didn't get that requirement from the OP, in that case `'BEGINFILE{flag=0}/<cert>/{flag=NR+1}/<\/cert>/&&flag==NR{print FILENAME; nextfile}'`

Comment: I believe the OP explained their goal in a since-deleted comment (looks like they were also able to delete my comment?). Yup, that looks right; in my opinion both solutions are about equally readable (three clauses either way), but using the record number is a nice alternative. But `FNR` seems more logical than `NR` to me somehow...

Comment: Using `FNR` would mean you could drop the `BEGINFILE` block however I agree the extra conditional does make both approaches equally readable.